# use trigger with update and insert query both in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

i have login page with user name and password, if the user forgot his/her password then there is a link of forgot password,were one has puts its email id and then the default password will send to its id and it will also update it in table with update query,the problem is that when in future we give this project to client we have truncate whole data and give him empty database, at that time update query won't work at that moment i need to use insert query, so i need a trigger query which fires on insert as well as on update query also later on when data is filled, please help because i never used trigger and i don't know its syntax, please explain me by showing an example

Comment: Holy stream of consciousness.  You need to write with better punctuation if you want to get help.

Comment: "Please help because I never _____ and I don't know its syntax" is never acceptable for any type of engineer. Read the manual. It has syntax and many examples.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a trigger. Just run an `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` query. It will insert a row, but if a row with the same primary key already exists, update the column in the existing row instead.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html